# Windows 7 taskbar folders minimize

Tags: windows-7

Does anyone know how to make each pinned folder minimize to its icons?

Answer (score 2):

Use the "Show Desktop" button

or use the Windows key + D

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Minimize-all-open-windows-to-view-the-desktop

Don't think there is a way to minimize pinned only.

Comment: i want to minimize folder to its icon, not all opened tasks to minimize. i dont like when folder like "docs" opened minimizes to explorer icon on taskbar.

Comment: I don't think you can change that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Win+number (1-9)`. For example, if you pin File Explorer and move to the 1st position on the task bar, then you can use `Win+1` to open or switch the File Explorer. And you can use `Win+Down arrow` to minimize it.

http://lifehacker.com/5390086/the-master-list-of-new-windows-7-shortcuts